# Stop integration after designated length of time in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

I want to stop solving a differential equation in Matlab if it takes more than a designated amount of time. I tried the following,but it doesn't work...

```
    options = odeset('AbsTol',1e-8,'RelTol',1e-5);
    RUNTIME=5;
    timerID = tic;
    while (toc(timerID) < RUNTIME)
        [t_pae,x_th_pae] = ode15s(@prosomoiwsh,[0 t_end],[80*pi/180;0;130*pi/180;0;th_initial(1);th_initial(2);th_initial(3);th_initial(4)],options);
    end
```

How can I solve this?

UPDATE : 
I tried what horchler suggested and now my code looks like this :

```
    interupt_time = 20;
    outputFun= @(t,y,flag)interuptFun(t,y,flag,interupt_time);
    options = odeset('AbsTol',1e-5,'RelTol',1e-5,'OutputFcn',outputFun);

    try
        [t_pae,x_b_th_pae] = ode15s(@prosomoiwsh,[0 t_end],[0;0;0;th_initial(1);th_initial(2);th_initial(3);th_initial(4);th_initial(5);th_initial(6);th_initial(7);th_initial(8);th_initial(9);th_initial(10);th_initial(11);th_initial(12)],options);
        u_pae=compute_input(epsilon,ke,kv,dD,IwF,IwG,IwD,IbF,IbG,IbD,p,m,t_pae,x_b_th_pae);  
    catch ME
        if strcmp(ME.identifier,'interuptFun:Interupt')
            disp(ME.message);
            input('got caught')
        else
            rethrow(ME); % It's possible the error was due to something else
        end
    end

   function dx_b_th = prosomoiwsh(t,x_b_th)
   ...
   end
```

The outputFun is exactly the same as the one horchler suggested. But now it times out every single time,while previously this only happened occasionally. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Is there an error? Please be specific.

Comment: Why would you want to abort a numerical integration by means of time? Better review your error tolerances.

Comment: @pyStarter: I don't know about the OP's case, but I can imagine cases where one might not have complete control over parameters or initial conditions. Or if one is sweeping through a parameter space, certain ODEs may have singularities or other phenomena that can cause numerical or other issues. Simply adjusting the tolerances will only reduce the precision of the results that are returned within a designated amount of time.

Comment: Yeah the thing is exactly what @horchler stated... I am calling the ODE from a GA and for some configurations of the parameters it takes ages until the warning "unable to lower the minimum step size" shows up. I tried increasing the minimum step of the solver,but since there is no straight way to do that,but through the tolerances either it did not work or I didn't manage to achieve it...

Comment: @darthbith there is no error,but if I try to repeat the code I wrote 5 times, it doesn't take 25 secs...It could take 5 hours...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can't do anything like what you're trying. All that will happen is that `ode15s` will run for as long as it needs and return it's result as usual. You need a way of interrupting the ODE solver in the middle of its execution when a certain designated amount of time has been exceeded. Unfortunately, you didn't provide runnable code, so I'll have to provide general suggestions that you can adapt to your problem.

One way to do this is via an [Output function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1016858). This is a function that gets called after every (successful) integration step of a Matlab solver. There are are several examples of Output functions that you can examine the code of to see what you can do: `odeplot`, `odeprint`, `odephas2`, and `odephas3`. Just type `edit odeplot` in your command window to see the code.

Below is an example of how you might use this capability using the built-in example function `vdp1000` that's referred to in the help for `ode15s`. You need to create a persistent variable to save the initial time, initialize it, and then check the elapsed time relative to a parameter that you pass in. Then you throw an error to abort `ode15s` if the elapsed time exceeds the designated value. A [`try`-`catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-trycatch-to-handle-errors.html) statement can be used to catch the error.

```
function ode_interupt_demo

tspan = [0 3000]; y0 = [2;0];
interupt_time = 0.05;
outputFun= @(t,y,flag)interuptFun(t,y,flag,interupt_time);
opts = odeset('AbsTol',1e-8,'RelTol',1e-5,'OutputFcn',outputFun);

try
    [t,y] = ode15s(@vdp1000,tspan,y0,opts);
catch ME
    if strcmp(ME.identifier,'interuptFun:Interupt')
        disp(ME.message);
        % Do other things
    else
        rethrow(ME); % It's possible the error was due to something else
    end
end


function status = interuptFun(t,y,flag,interupt_time)   %#ok<INUSL>
persistent INIT_TIME;
status = 0;
switch(flag)
    case 'init'
        INIT_TIME = tic;
    case 'done'
        clear INIT_TIME;
    otherwise
        elapsed_time = toc(INIT_TIME);
        if elapsed_time > interupt_time
            clear INIT_TIME;
            str = sprintf('%.6f',elapsed_time);
            error('interuptFun:Interupt',...
                 ['Interupted integration. Elapsed time is ' str ' seconds.']);
        end
end
```

One disadvantage of this approach is that you will not get a return value from `ode15s`. This may or may not be desirable in your application. There are likely ways around this, but they'll require more code. One easy thing that you can do is have the error message return the last time and state of the system (when it was interrupted) using the `t` and `y` values passed into the output function. It's also possible that [Event functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1017470) could be used to terminate integration based on elapsed time – those might allow you to still return output from `ode15s`.

Comment: I don't know if people get notified when the initial post is edited,so could you take a look please?

Comment: @PavlosTriantafyllou: Hard to say much as your updated code isn't runnable either. The absolute integration tolerances are different between the two cases. If you set `interupt_time` to a much larger value will return some or all of the time (you referred to 25 seconds in a comment above)?

Comment: I rerun the code and it seems that it was the case that all the configurations I tried before where "problematic". It works fine. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks again!

Comment: If you want to add an event example, this would be one way:
`function [position,isterminal,direction] = time_EventsFcn(~,y, timer)
position(1:3) = y(1:3) - .0001; % The value that we want to be zero
if 180 - toc(timer) < 0 % Halt if he has not finished in 3 minutes
    position(1:3) = 0;
end
isterminal(1:3) = 1;  % Halt integration 
direction(1:3) = 0; % The zero can be approached from either direction
end`
Calling solver with options:
`timer = tic;
opts = odeset('Event', @(t,y) time_EventsFcn(t,y,timer))
ode15s(@(t,y) some_ode(t,y), t_int, y0, opts);`