# Matlab - sometimes ode45 takes long time to return

Tags: matlab, ode

Here is the code

```
global a b c
a=35
b=3
c=28

for R = a-3 : a+3
    for N = b-2 : b+2
        for L = c-2 : c+2
            a=R;
            b=N;
            c=L;
            ode_interupt_demo
            plot3(x(:,3), x(:,2), x(:,1));
            S= [R N L]
            pause(1)
            close
        end
    end
end

function dxdt=fun1(t,x)
global a b c
 
dxdt(1)=a*(x(2)-x(1));
dxdt(2)=(c-a)*x(1)-x(1)*x(3)+c*x(2);
dxdt(3)=x(1)*x(2)-b*x(3);
dxdt=dxdt';
end

function status = interuptFun(t,y,flag,interupt_time)   %#ok<INUSL>
persistent INIT_TIME;
status = 0;
switch(flag)
    case 'init'
        INIT_TIME = tic;
    case 'done'
        clear INIT_TIME;
    otherwise
        elapsed_time = toc(INIT_TIME);
        if elapsed_time > interupt_time
            clear INIT_TIME;
            str = sprintf('%.6f',elapsed_time);
            error('interuptFun:Interupt',...
                 ['Interupted integration. Elapsed time is ' str ' seconds.']);
        end
end


function ode_interupt_demo

tspan = [0 10]; y0 = [0.5 1 1];
interupt_time = 10;
outputFun= @(t,y,flag)interuptFun(t,y,flag,interupt_time);
opts = odeset('AbsTol',1e-8,'RelTol',1e-5,'OutputFcn',outputFun);

try
    [t,x] = ode45(@fun1,tspan,y0,opts);
    
catch ME
    if strcmp(ME.identifier,'interuptFun:Interupt')
        disp(ME.message);
        % Do other things
    else
        rethrow(ME); % It's possible the error was due to something else
    end
end
```

In Matlab I am solving a differential equation, but sometimes it takes `ode45` a long time to return. I have used code that was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25583703/2278029) to solve my similar problem, but it will not return a value from `ode45`. Instead I get

> ??? Undefined variable x.
>
> Error in ==> goo at 13
> plot3(x(:,3), x(:,2), x(:,1));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says... undefined variable `x`.  You haven't defined it anywhere in your code, yet you start instantly using it at line 13.  However, there is a function call just before line 13, and it looks like the ODE solving is performed there... but you're not returning `x` from the function call.  Remember, any variables defined in a function are of local scope.  This means that upon exit, those variables that were previously declared disappear... unless you make the variable `global` or `persistent`.

Because you want to use `x` after the function call, the easiest thing to fix your code would be to modify the function definition so that it returns `x`, and assign `x` to be the output of the function call before you use it.

Therefore, modify your `ode_interupt_demo` function declaration so that it does this:

```
function x = ode_interupt_demo
```

Next, make line 12 do this:

```
x = ode_interupt_demo;
```

The code should now work.

Comment: Good debugging. The code is taken from [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25583703/2278029). The `ode_interupt_demo` function was meant to be a "main" function in that example, so another alternative would be to just modify the code for `ode_interupt_demo` directly and do all of the plotting from there.

Comment: @horchler thanks for the link! Was wondering where that came from.

Comment: @Abneh - You're welcome :) Please consider accepting my answer if you no longer need help.  That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left just below the up and down arrows.  Good luck!

Comment: one more thing please

Comment: one more thing please   how do you have the error message return the last time and state of the system (when it was interrupted) using the t and y values passed into the output function ( as was mentioned in similar post)

Comment: I didn't write the function you are referencing. Ask @horchler.

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer. I believe I have solved this issue.

Comment: Dear Horchler, can you help of how do you have the error message return the last time and state of the system (when it was interrupted) using the t and y values passed into the output function ( as was mentioned in similar post)

Comment: @horchler   can you help of how do you have the error message return the last time and state of the system (when it was interrupted) using the t and y values passed into the output function ( as was mentioned in similar post) –  Abneh May 27 at 7:23

Comment: @Abneh - Please stop using this post to try and communicate with horchler.... mainly because I'm getting annoyed receiving notifications in my inbox.  If you continue, I'm going to delete my answer.