# Using persistent variable to pass out extra parameters using ode45 from the MATLAB ODE suite?

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

In [How do I pass out extra parameters using ODE23 or ODE45 from the MATLAB ODE suite?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92701-how-do-i-pass-out-extra-parameters-using-ode23-or-ode45-from-the-matlab-ode-suite) the "MathWorks Support Team" suggests using a `persistent` variable to pass out extra parameters using `ode45` from the MATLAB ODE suite.

However, what if an integration failed and solver will call your function for the previous time step? The `ode45` solver uses an adaptive time step, and sometimes integration can fail, so the solver automatically decreases time step, and "has to go back."

Is "MathWorks Support Team" wrong in their suggestion of using a `persistent` variable? I see that the `'OutputFcn'` method can be used to pass out extra parameters, but I do not know how to use it. Could you give me an outline or example code using the `'OutputFcn'` method to detect failed steps / flag etc. to give the correct extra parameters? If I use the `'OutputFcn'` method, is a `global` variable needed?

Comment: Your concerns are correct, and Output Functions are the right way to solve the problem. The documentation is in http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#input_argument_namevalue_outputfcn. You will have to define a global variable in the Output Functions, and in the odefun.

Comment: @Jommy Thanks. I have tried using `outputFcn` for many attempts but i do not have a general outline on how to use it and if how to define or which to define a global variable/s. Can you give me an outline or example code on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, slightly modified from the documentation.

Define the ODE function. `param` will be the variable to be exchanged.

```
function dy = rigid(t, y)

global param

dy = zeros(3,1);    % a column vector
dy(1) = param + y(2) * y(3);
dy(2) = -y(1) * y(3);
dy(3) = -0.51 * y(1) * y(2);

param = dy(1) * dy(3);
```

The output function must declare the variable to be exchanged as global. `myout` will be called after each successful step.

```
function status = myout(t, y, flag)

global param

% Don't ever halt the integration
status = 0;

if strcmp(flag, 'init')
    % Initialization (apparently useless).
    param = -2;

elseif isempty(flag)
     % Main code to update param.
     param = param * mean(t);

elseif strcmp(flag, 'done')
     % Nothing to do.

end
```

Call `ode45` in this way.

```
% True initialization.
global param
param = -2;

odeOpts = odeset(  ...
    'RelTol', 1e-6,  ...
    'AbsTol', 1e-7,  ...
    'OutputFcn', @myout);

[time, y] = ode45(@rigid, [0 10], [0 1 1], odeOpts);

plot(  ...
    time, y(:,1), '-',   ...
    time, y(:,2), '-.',  ...
    time, y(:,3), '.');
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this method work if param depends on `t`, say `param = dy(1) * dy(3) * t`?

Comment: Of course, and you can also make param a vector, and accumulate values.

Comment: @kww: As per [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#zmw57dd0e572702), "The ODE solver calls the output function after each successful time step." You don't need to worry about unsuccessful steps.

Comment: @Jommy: one could also use [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) to avoid the potential performance hit from `global` variables (though this usage is not necessarily a bad one).

Comment: Also, a `switch` statement will be more efficient that using `strcmp`. Just put the `isempty(flag)` case in the `otherwise` block (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25583703/2278029)).